# Make clickable text to another UIViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, href, uicontrol

I have a block of text shown like:

[image: this]

What I am trying to accomplish is that when I add the test to this table view cell, I want to make a specific word or group of words clickable.  Lets take the group of words Grand Turk Lighthouse for example.  Is there a way to add a href to the word that when I click it, it will send me to say View2 which is in the app.  I am building an app that will not go to the internet and so I want a way for the link to be clickable to send to another page within the app.  Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you specific answer, but you may try this :

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel

it also could give different style, color, and href in one label.

[image]

another alternative, is to use UIWebView, and listen / delegate to it. load html within the app.

hope it helps.